# Pagination in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to assign number of rows to my GridView.

Example:

```
GridView1.Rows.Count = 500;
```

More My code

```
using (CEntities context = new CEntities())
            {

                Users = context.Procedure(0,10).ToList<Procedure_Result>();
            }
            GridView1.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
            GridView1.DataSource = Users;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

I will explain this problem much more clearly:

I wrote this context.Procedure(0,10) I get only 10 elements and one page. Normally I have 500 elements (rows). I search place where can I write value of all my rows. Otherwise I will not see other my pages.

Example of my problem in JTable Grid -> StudentsCount (I want make similar version in GridView to make this GridView very fast. Simple way I know. )

http://jtable.org/Tutorials/UsingWithAspNetWebFormsPageMethods

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static object StudentList(int jtStartIndex, int jtPageSize, string jtSorting)
{
    try
    {
        //Get data from database
        int studentCount = Repository.StudentRepository.GetStudentCount();
        List<Student> students = Repository.StudentRepository.GetStudents(jtStartIndex, jtPageSize, jtSorting);

        //Return result to jTable
        return new { Result = "OK", Records = students, TotalRecordCount = studentCount };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message };
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want a gridview with 500 empty rows?

Comment: Then create a datasource with `row-count` records.

Comment: Do you want to add 500 empty rows?

Comment: I have got data but if using AllowPaging="True" and data is generated automatically my GridView in second page see only 10 elements and other page in footer disappeared

Comment: Gridview.Rows.Count is a read only property (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrowcollection.count%28v=vs.110%29.aspx ) absolutely not intended to what you want to do. I suggest you to edit your question : rather than asking "how I change property X", ask : "how I handle pagination in gridview" (or anything else you want)

Comment: if you want to get some Answwers than first show your effort on asking a question which one can understand what your problem is and where you show what goal you want to reach. Your current question isn't worth on putting any effort on answering it. Even that comment was nearly too much time. I think it took much more time than you spent on thinking about your question and writing it down...

Comment: @Richard I changed title of my question

Comment: I'm having a hard time to decipher your question. Show us something. Make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply paging in your GridView.
You can try this.

Markup

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gridview" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" OnPageIndexChanging="gridview_PageIndexChanging" runat="server" />
```

Code behind

```
protected void gridview_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
  //Fill grid here
  gridview.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
  gridview.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Can you check my explanation because now my explanation is clear.

Comment: This is not what I want but I will accept your answer. I know this, and unfortunately it is a very slowly method. Thanks again for your time.